# Why is spam verification necessary for users with more than 3000 reputation points?

Tags: feature-request, captcha

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Please stop asking me a captcha with over 500 reputation. I AM A HUMAN](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81012/please-stop-asking-me-a-captcha-with-over-500-reputation-i-am-a-human)
>   [Why is Captcha for higher rep users even necessary?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3346/why-is-captcha-for-higher-rep-users-even-necessary)

This is really bugging me nowadays.

All of the users who uses any Stack Exchange site know one thing for sure. And that is, earning reputation is not as easy as it sounds here.

Now, since we have a common agreement on this, I think the users with above 3000 reputation have already proven to the community that they are not **`SPAM`**. Then why are they asked spam verification time and again?

I suggest the spam verifications for 3000+ users to be removed.

Comment: Hmm, at what point *are* the spam verifications removed? I don't ever see any on Stack Overflow, although I'm well over 3000 reps there.

Comment: Well, I often get it. And its seriously bugging me. Once I thought I posted my answer and changed the tab, when I came back to see the comments, it was never posted. It was stuck asking spam verification. Arrrrrrrr

Comment: When exactly do you get it? Can you reproduce it always? It should appear only when unusual activity is identified e.g. editing in less than one second which can mean spam bot.

Comment: Also see: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67554/my-reputation-is-100-and-i-still-get-captcha/67556#67556

Comment: I wonder if they turned them off for mods, haven't seen one in a long time...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Even High-Rep-Accounts can be hijacked. Just because somebody was a 'normal' and 'good' user in the past, doesn't mean that he (or someone else with his account) is not going rogue on us.

Comment: Well, I can't say no to your point. But, I think our community is powerful enough to handle anyone who tries to `rogue` on us.

Comment: Sorry but -1. What's the likelihood a high rep account is compromised? Are you aware of a **single** high rep account that has been compromised in the entire history of stack overflow? Do you think this close-to-0 chance is worth inconveniencing thousands of users who are donating their time to improve the website? It's like advising everyone to always go out with a bucket of water just in case a lightning strikes you and sets you on fire. Sure, if you are hit by a lightning it'll be useful, but you can't just ignore the fact that walking with a bucket of water is just plain annoying.

Comment: @Kop, would you mind, if i say "That was what I was trying to say" ?

Comment: @Kop, did you mean: what is the likelihood for it [to happen again](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/08/protecting-your-cookies-httponly.html)? ;-) (And there's still [the Firesheep threat](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69171/why-doesnt-the-stack-overflow-team-fix-the-firesheep-style-cookie-theft), and this week myOpenID [failed badly](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88451/myopenid-account-mysteriously-vanished/88456#88456).)